# Erro ao executar checklist dos Campos

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$funcionario_materiais = array();
foreach($_POST AS $key=>$val){
    $tmp = explode("_",$key);
    if($tmp[0]=="materiais"){
        $funcionario_materiais[$tmp[1]]=$val;
        unset($_POST[$key]);
    }
}

$funcionario_materiais_novo = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($funcionario_materiais['material']);$i++){
    foreach($funcionario_materiais as $key=>$val){
        $funcionario_materiais_novo[$i][$key]= $funcionario_materiais[$key][$i];
        $funcionario_materiais_novo[$i]['idFuncionario'] = $ultimo_id;
        $funcionario_materiais_novo[$i]['data'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($funcionario_materiais_novo[$i]['data']));                
    }
}
```

Mas na hora de executar, dá um erro:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: data
>   Filename: controllers/funcionario.php
>   Line Number: 246

Esta é a linha 246:

```
$funcionario_materiais_novo[$i]['data'] = 
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime($funcionario_materiais_novo[$i]['data']));
```

Penso eu que é por causa que dentro dos campos, uns foram preenchidos e outros não.
Pois é um *array*, e pode vir preenchido ou não. Mas não sei como verificar se o campo está ou não preenchido, dentro do *foreach*...
Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço muito!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// verifica se existe a posição no array
if (array_key_exists("data", $funcionario_materiais_novo[$i])) {
        // seu codigo
        $funcionario_materiais_novo[$i]['data'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($funcionario_materiais_novo[$i]['data']));
}
```

Coloca isso dentro do seu foreach. Isso deve funcionar. :)